# Problems converting an iterative algorithm to a recursive one

Tags: algorithm, vba, recursion

I haven't looked into recursion in a long time so please be patient with me.

I basically needs to write a subroutine that will output all sequence of numbers if they totaled a given number. An iterative approach is shown in the following section

```
Sub IterFunc()
    For i = 1 To 5
        For j = 1 To 5
            For k = 1 To 5
                If i + j + k = 4 Then
                    Debug.Print i & ", " & j & ", " & k
                End If
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

This works fine if the sequence consists of 3 integers, however it will not work for an arbitrary number of integers in the sequence. So a recursive approach is then needed. The following is my attempt to rewrite a recursive version of the subroutine

```
Sub RecuFunc(ByRef tot As Long)
    For i = 1 To 5
        tot = tot + i
        If tot = 5 Then
            Debug.Print i
        ElseIf tot < 5 Then
            Call RecuFunc(tot)
        ElseIf tot > 5 Then
            Call RecuFunc(tot - i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Sub test2()
    Call RecuFunc(0)
End Sub
```

Several problems quickly arise: a) I am not quite sure how to store the sequence to output it when the total matches b) it seems that I need to somehow "reset" the variable `tot`, but my approach doesn't seem to be working.

Any ideas would be great. And I apologize if my question is primitive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive function which, given an integer `n` and a target value, `target` (assumed to be > 0), returns a collection of all strings of the form e.g. `"1 + 2 + 1 + 1"`, where the numbers in the sum are in the range 1,..., n and they sum to the target. A collection is a natural data structure to use and the advantage of using strings is that it is easy to tack on new terms to the sum:

```
Function IntSums(n As Long, target As Long) As Collection
    Dim sums As New Collection
    Dim partialSums As Collection
    Dim i As Long, m As Long, sum As Variant

    If target = 1 Then
        sums.Add target
        Set IntSums = sums
        Exit Function
    End If
    m = IIf(n < target, n, target) 'm is min(n,target)
    For i = 1 To m
        If i = target Then
            sums.Add Trim(Str(target))
        Else
            Set partialSums = IntSums(n, target - i)
            For Each sum In partialSums
                sums.Add i & " + " & sum
            Next sum
        End If
    Next i
    Set IntSums = sums
End Function
```

A test function:

```
Sub test()
    Dim s As Variant, sum As Variant
    Set s = IntSums(5, 5)
    For Each sum In s
        Debug.Print sum
    Next sum
End Sub
```

Output:

```
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
1 + 1 + 1 + 2
1 + 1 + 2 + 1
1 + 1 + 3
1 + 2 + 1 + 1
1 + 2 + 2
1 + 3 + 1
1 + 4
2 + 1 + 1 + 1
2 + 1 + 2
2 + 2 + 1
2 + 3
3 + 1 + 1
3 + 2
4 + 1
5
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is list partitions of a number with a restricted number of parts. Here's a recursion in JavaScript, a language with syntax not too distant from C:

```js
function ps(n,k,max,r){
  if (n == 0){
    console.log(r.substr(1));
    return;
  }

  for (var i=Math.min(max,n-k+1); i*k>=n; i--){
    ps(n - i,k - 1,i,r + "," + i);
  }
}

ps(8,3,8,"")

/*
6,1,1
5,2,1
4,3,1
4,2,2
3,3,2
*/
```

For the unrestricted version, we remove `k`:

```js
function ps(n,max,r){
  if (n == 0){
    console.log(r.substr(1));
  }

  for (var i=Math.min(max,n); i>0; i--){
    ps(n - i,i,r + "," + i);
  }
}

ps(8,8,"")
```

Comment: This is nice. I wasn't sure if OP wanted a restricted number of parts (but without the number hardwired in as 3) or if OP wanted all sums with no restriction on the number of parts. It is good to have two answers which solve two different variations of the integer sum problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a complete answer here - I don't know VB - but to get you started in the right direction. Several observations: firstly, usually iterative > recursive. Secondly, you are doing brute force where possibly a more efficient method could be found. Consider breaking a total value of say 10 into a sum of say three integers :
10 = 3 + 5 + 2 = (1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1)
10 = 4 + 5 + 1 = (1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1)+(1)
As you can see, basically you are shifting around where the parenthesis are placed. As far as recursion, breaking a 10 into three sums could be done by subtracting the "i" from 10 and then recursively breaking the (10-i) into two sums.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nicko, I am having hard time understanding your description, I still can read C if you want to add some code :)